# Is it possible to control program flow during debug in .NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm debugging an app in VS2010 and I would like that the next instruction don't execute. Is it possible without recompiling the app?

Comment: Edit + Continue support makes this trivial, just edit the code.  That doesn't require recompiling the app.  Noticeably anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

Just drag the yellow line (highlighted line which is on the line executing) to the line after the one you do not want to run.

[image]

Comment: Or alternatively you can open the context menu in another line and `Set Next Statement`

Comment: Though dragging and dropping is better if your system isn't running slow.  For laggy debugging however, go for the context menu.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, right click on the line after and go "Set Next Statement", this forces execution onto that line.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for how to [set the next execution point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09yze4a9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (MSDN).